# How to add pytorch library to Google App Engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pip

I'm trying to add `torch==1.7.0+cpu` and `torchvision==0.8.1+cpu` libraries to GAE,

from my OS I can use `pip install torch==1.7.0+cpu torchvision==0.8.1+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` to install them, but on google app engine deployment it takes libraries from `requirements.txt` only.

I tried downloading them to a `lib` folder via `pip install torch==1.7.0+cpu torchvision==0.8.1+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html -t lib/` and adding to `appengine_config.py`

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

but I keep getting  `This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.`,

any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by editing the `requirements.txt` file to:

```
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==1.7.0+cpu
torchvision==0.8.1+cpu
```